# Visual Studio Code Color Theme

Tags: visual-studio-code

Just a quick question - does anyone knows what Color Theme is being used to showcase the updates for September 2019 (version 1.39) ?
https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_39#vscode

Here is the image from the link I attached. Thanks!

https://code.visualstudio.com/assets/updates/1_39/scm.gif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure its [GitHub Sharp](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=joaomoreno.github-sharp-theme) theme. Not sure if it's the same folder icons or what not but the base seems to be GitHub Sharp!